# How does this Array.prototype and bind combination replace this arrow function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, bind, arrow-functions

I'm reading trough this: https://hackernoon.com/functional-javascript-resolving-promises-sequentially-7aac18c4431e

and in one section the author talks about replacing the second arrow function with

```
Promise.resolve([])
    .then(all => funcs[0].then(result => all.concat(result)))
```

this

```
Promise.resolve([])
    .then(all => funcs[0].then(Array.prototype.concat.bind(all)))
```

I'm having trouble understanding how this works... Is the returned result being added as an argument implicitly into the concat function?

Comment: When calling a function that expects a function as an argument, you can either write a new function inline, e.g. `foo(() => {...})` or pass a reference to an existing function, e.g. `foo(myCallback)`. This example is using the `bind()` function to do the latter. But personally I don't see the advantage of using `bind()` in this situation; generally arrow functions are clearer with no performance downside (at least nowadays).

Comment: Well technically the `bind()` call isn't a reference to an existing function but returns a new function, but it's the same general idea - using an existing function instead of creating a new one inline.

Answer (score 1):

`whatEverMethod.bind(thisValue)` binds `this` to `thisValue`.

To understand, we can assume (though not actually) every method call

```
obj.method(arg0)
```

to equal to

```
obj.method.apply(obj, arg0)
```

where the first argument of `.apply` explicitly tells: which object I am working on (because likely in the definition of `.method` you may reference to some `this` value, such as `this.prop0 = 10`)

What `bind` does is very simple: bind a `this` value to a method call, so that when called, no longer uses the default `this` value based on environment.

For example:

```js
let obj0 = {a: 1}
let obj1 = {a: 2}
obj0.change = function(value) {
  this.a = value;
} // when declared, default environment is obj0, since it is a method of obj0

// Now, explicitly bind `this` inside of obj0.change to obj1
let changeFunc = obj0.change.bind(obj1);
// This creates a function that has `this` set to obj1, which has the format changeFunc(value)
changeFunc(10);

console.log(obj1.a) // should be 10, since it is now operating on obj1 (due to binding)
```

Therefore,

```js
(Array.prototype.concat.bind(all))(someArr)
// is basically
all.concat(someArr)
// due to having the exactly the same `this` value
```

The reason why we may want to do this is probably `all` may not be an array. For example, it might be an array-like object, such as the `arguments` for functions, which looks like an array, but missing common array methods.

Answer (score 0):

[`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) operates on a function, taking a value for `this` and returning a new function that calls the original function with the specified `this` value and the same arguments¹. In other words,

```
Array.prototype.concat.bind(all)
```

means

```
(...args) => Array.prototype.concat.call(all, ...args)
```

which is

```
(...args) => all.concat(...args)
```

and since one argument is being passed, that’s

```
result => all.concat(result)
```

There is no reason not to just write the arrow function here, by the way. It’s clearer and has no downsides.

<sub>¹ it can also add arguments.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

- As you must know, the function `then` receives a function/callback.
- The function `bind` returns a function attaching a specific object as context `this`.

---

```
 Array.prototype.concat.bind(all))
                             ^
                             |
                             +---- This object 'all' will be the context
                                   'this' for the function 'concat'.
```

So, the function `then` will call the `callback` (passing the `all` object implicitly) which is the new function returned by the function `bind`, in this case, the function `concat` from Array prototype.

## Resource

- [`Function.prototype.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

  > The `bind()` method creates a new function that, when called, has its this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.